# Facebook account visible to friends even after deactivation

Tags: facebook, facebook-account

I deactivated(not deleted) my facebook account 2 days back thinking that my profile would not be available to rest of the world. But what I see here is that my friends can still visit my facebook profile, they actually can message me, post something on my wall, search my profile which pops-up in their search results. But if I hit the direct URL of my profile without logged-in it gives "Content Not Available" but my logged-in friends can see my profile.

Is there any recent policy that facebook made for Account Deactivation?

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate or delete your account at any time.

You may deactivate your account for any number of temporary reasons. This option gives you the flexibility to leave and come back whenever you want. If you deactivate your account:

People won’t be able to see the information on your Timeline on Facebook.

- People on Facebook will not be able to search for you.
- Some information, like messages you sent, may still be visible to others.
- We save the information in your account (ex: friends, photos, interests), just in case you want to come back to Facebook at some point. If you choose to reactivate your account, the information on your profile will be there when you come back.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that after account deactivation Facebook leaves your account up for two weeks in case you change your mind.  It's probably worth waiting for two weeks and then seeing if it's still visible to your friends.